# Unable to move data of 10 GB into pod with storage capacity of 20Gi

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pvc

I am trying to copy data from my local system to kubernetes pods with ebs backed volumes[Storage 20Gi]. While running the command
`kubectl cp /path/to/file redis/redis-master-0:/data/`
It is getting haulted after 1GB. What could be the possible reason for this ?

Copy from local to Pods
`kubectl cp /path/to/file redis/redis-master-0:/data/`

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Can you please share the error message?